# ZSH and ZLE, move to the beginning-of-line, write string, move to the end

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, prezto, zsh-zle

Its not essential but it bugs me a bit,
here is the fragment from my .zshrc

a function/widget called add_sudo, that will go at the beginning of line, writes sudo there and then should go at the end of the line.

Its bind to ctrl+f

But it does not go at the end of the line, it ignores last command and sits there after it wrote sudo.

```
add_sudo() {
  zle beginning-of-line;
  zle -U "sudo ";
  zle end-of-line;
}

zle -N add_sudo
bindkey "^f" add_sudo
```

any solution to this?

Comment: You should probably modify `$BUFFER` directly (i.e., `BUFFER="sudo $BUFFER"`), then move `$CURSOR` (i.e., `(( CURSOR += 5 ))`). Pushing into the input stack is, as you see, totally unintuitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can answer this one! I just joined, glad to help..... and I read the question wrong, but now I'm here to redeem myself, with the help of @4ae1e1, all credit to him for mentioning to use BUFFER= and CURSOR=

```
add_sudo (){
prefix="sudo"
BUFFER="$prefix $BUFFER"
CURSOR=$(($CURSOR + $#prefix + 1))
}
zle -N add_sudo
bindkey "^f" add_sudo
```

Does what you would like, and now I can use this after every time I forget to sudo, too!

EDITx2

Of note, this actually places the cursor back to wherever it was prior, my preferred use. You can, as 4aelel stated, use CURSOR+=5 to place it at the end of the line.

Also of note, again, I realized I truly haven't fulfilled the question, as it was how to do this with zsh and zli, rather than how to do this. If I come across an answer I'll append with both solutions.I'm new to zli and it's nuances, just recently moving to zsh.

Comment: I noticed you have this tagged as Prezto, if you do in fact use it, it appears this functionality already exists in keyboard.zsh, see this commit https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/commit/9f8b41aaec63076d25b41b41c85c9244576c2cdb